# Can I use dpkg on vagrant and point it to a deb file on a local folder?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, devops

I am trying to test the build of a .deb file and I would like to see if it installs on my vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file in the vagrant folder - should see it once I do vagrant ssh and then use dpkg on it.